# Django for loop save instance

Tags: python, django

I have a form that has two input fields which are returning the id values that will have to be parsed and added into the database.

This is the code

```
        if form_stage_1.is_valid() and form_stage_2.is_valid():
        # GET the new TP to pass to the next instance

        form_stage_1.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        new_tp = form_stage_1.save()


        # Parse and add suppliers to the TP
        for supplier_id in request.POST["supplier"]:
            form_stage_2.instance.counterpart = Counterpart.objects.get(pk=supplier_id)
            form_stage_2.instance.side = 1
            form_stage_2.instance.save()
            form_stage_2.instance.transaction_proposal.add(new_tp)


        # Parse and add clients to the TP
        for client_id in request.POST["client"]:
            form_stage_2.instance.counterpart = Counterpart.objects.get(pk=client_id)
            form_stage_2.instance.side = 2
            form_stage_2.instance.save()
            form_stage_2.instance.transaction_proposal.add(new_tp)

        messages.success(request, "TP created successfully".format())
        return redirect("add-tp")
```

Unfortunately is only adding one client.. why the form_stage_2.instance.save() is only working once?

What would be the most appropriate way to

Comment: What is the instance that you want to save in form_stage_2? You need to initiate that record in for loop and call save method after you fill required information. You have only one instance in form_stage_2, so the code only save that instance you defined in form_stage_2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have 2 forms to fill in ?

Anyway,

```
for supplier_id in request.POST["supplier"]:
            form_stage_2.instance.counterpart = Counterpart.objects.get(pk=supplier_id)
            form_stage_2.instance.side = 1
            form_stage_2.instance.save()
            form_stage_2.instance.transaction_proposal.add(new_tp)
```

This won't work. You can't save a form instance multiple times I believe.

```
if form_stage_1.is_valid() and form_stage_2.is_valid():
    form_stage_1.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    new_tp = form_stage_1.save()

    # Parse and add suppliers to the TP
    for supplier_id in request.POST["supplier"]:
        data = {
            'counterpart':Counterpart.objects.get(pk=supplier_id),
            'side':1
            'transaction_proposal':[new_tp]
        }
        stage2_instance = Stage2ModelClass.objects.create(**data)


    # Parse and add clients to the TP
    for client_id in request.POST["client"]:
        data = {
            'counterpart':Counterpart.objects.get(pk=client_id),
            'side':2
            'transaction_proposal':[new_tp]
        }
        stage2_instance = Stage2ModelClass.objects.create(**data)

    messages.success(request, "TP created successfully".format())
    return redirect("add-tp")
```

Solution can be somewhat like this. 
You can use,

```
    for client_id in request.POST["client"]:
        data = {
            'counterpart':Counterpart.objects.get(pk=client_id),
            'side':2,
            'transaction_proposal':[new_tp]
        }
        form = FormClassStage2(data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

But I don't think you need to initialize a form here.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I've just fixed a bit the code, because "transaction_proposal" is a ManyToMany field and couldn't be call directly.

 for client_id in request.POST["client"]:
        for client_id in request.POST["client"]:
        data = {
            'counterpart':Counterpart.objects.get(pk=client_id),
            'side':2
        }
        stage2_instance = Stage2ModelClass.objects.create(**data)
        stage2_instance.transaction_proposal.add(new_tp)